# How to get the column name which causes the SqlException?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlexception

**Q:** How can i get the column name which causes the `SqlException`?

**C:** I am working with SQL Server. My data which I get from my database is visualized with C# / WPF datagrid / DataTable.

If I want to insert an new datarecord to the database where I for example forgot to put some data in a cell which can not be NULL, I will get a `SqlException` with the message:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column '%.*ls', table '%.*ls';
>   column does not allow nulls. %ls fails.

`'%.*ls'` is replaced automatically by the columnname which causes the `SqlException`.

Is there a way to get this column name mentioned in the error message. Or do I have to extract it from the message string myself?

Comment: Regex in Message would help

Comment: cant you just validate your entries to make sure that someone doesnt forget to input data in the first place? Seems like a strange way to handle such an issue

Comment: Regex is definitely the way to go here.

Comment: If you mean how can you get it programmatically, then yes, you have to parse the exception message.   There isn't any property that contains just the column name.

Comment: In SQL SERVER 2012 it is giving me `Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Amount', table 'dbBlink.wlt.WalletTransactionDetail'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.` why it is specifying column name 'Amount'??

Comment: @psoshmo: validate the entries would be for sure the better option. But thats an issue for the second iteration of enhancement ;)  i just thought that the columnname is saved in some property i have acces to. But Ok.

Comment: @Dave as others have said, I am pretty sure the only way to get it is by parsing the exception message. by the time you go through all that trouble, it may actually be EASIER to add some simple required field validation